# How to grep values under columns

Tags: regex, grep, awk

How can I grep for a specific column name and display the value underneath that column.

Sample data:

```
StandByFile  StandByPg  StandByLSN         StandByRcvBufUsed
S0082160.LOG 621668     0x00000C85118BC72D 0%
```

I want to display `0%` under `StandByRcvBufUsed` column.
Mind you that file contains other data different from the above displayed columns, meaning there are different column lists in files on different rows.

Thanks

**Update:**
My file has the following format, so the column #s are not fixed:

```
HADR Information:
Role    State                SyncMode   HeartBeatsMissed   LogGapRunAvg (bytes)
Standby Peer                 Async    0                  365000              

ConnectStatus ConnectTime                           Timeout   
Connected     Tue May 20 09:34:23 2014 (1400592863) 120       

ReplayOnlyWindowStatus ReplayOnlyWindowStartTime             MaintenanceTxCount
Inactive               N/A                                   0         


PrimaryFile  PrimaryPg  PrimaryLSN        
S0082160.LOG 621668     0x00000C85118BC72D

StandByFile  StandByPg  StandByLSN         StandByRcvBufUsed
S0082160.LOG 621668     0x00000C85118BC72D 0%
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look for the number of column that contains `StandByRcvBufUsed` and store it. Then, jump to the next line and print that column and finally exit:

```
$ awk 'f{print $f; exit} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "StandByRcvBufUsed") {f=i; next}}' file
0%
```

Comment: but my file has the following format:              

ConnectStatus ConnectTime                           Timeout   
Connected     Tue May 20 09:34:23 2014 (1400592863) 120       

                                0         
PrimaryFile  PrimaryPg  PrimaryLSN        
S0082160.LOG 621668     0x00000C85118BC72D

StandByFile  StandByPg  StandByLSN         StandByRcvBufUsed
S0082160.LOG 621668     0x00000C85118BC72D 0%

Comment: Please update your question with this information, in comments it is quite difficult to see code.

Comment: So given this file, what is your exactly required output, @user327963 ?

Comment: I would like to see the value under StandByRcvBufUsed which would be 0% in this case.Thanks

Comment: Ok, @user327963 see my updated answer. Now it makes it.

Comment: it does not work for me. I get nothing:

Comment: awk 'f{print $f; exit} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i =="StandByRcvBufUsed") 
{f=i; next}}' 79742.7TD.000.Pmr79742DRhadr.out

Comment: @user327963 it works fine with my awk: `mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996`. Cross check if you are writing the fields properly.

Comment: what about if we use grep to search for column name and pipe it to awk to print its value?

Comment: i have it worked as follows:

Comment: cat <file> |head -24|tail -1| awk '{ print $4 }'
0%

Comment: Nice to read that, @user327963 . However, you ended up using the col number (`$4`) and line number (`head -24`). Anyway, good that you found your desired result.

Comment: yes thanks!!! it would be good to have a flexible way to do this instead of knowing the line # :)

Comment: @user327963 well this is what I tried with my solution: get the column number and then print that column on the next line.